# $\mathcal{B}$ is maximal Abelian subalgebra iff it concides with its commutant

Tags: functional-analysis, algebras

I'm reading the book [*Hilbert Space Operators in Quantum Physics*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4020-8870-4) and I come to **Chapter 6: Operator sets and algebras**. Before reading this chapter, I need to first read the [Appendix B](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-1-4020-8870-4%2F1.pdf), where I met my problem, which is Proposition B.1.2.

**Definition.** A *maximal Abelian subalgebra* is $\color{red}{\text{an Abelian subalgebra(after editting)}}$ such that it is not a proper subalgebra of an Abelian subalgebra.

> **Problem.** Suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra, i.e. a complex associative linear algebra, and $\mathcal{B}$ is a subalgebra in $\mathcal{A}$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is maximal Abelian iff $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{B}'$. Here $\mathcal{B}'$ is the *commutant*:
> $$\mathcal{B}'=\{a\in\mathcal{A}: ab=ba,b\in\mathcal{B}\}.$$

The sufficiency is OK for me. If $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{B}'$ and $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{T}$ for some Abelian subalgebra $\mathcal{T}$, then
$$\mathcal{T}\subset\mathcal{T}'\subset\mathcal{B}'=\mathcal{B},$$
so $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{T}$. By definition, $\mathcal{B}$ is maximal Abelian.

I'm stuck on the neccessity so I'm asking for some help here. If $\mathcal{B}$ is maximal Abelian, $\style{text-decoration:line-through}{\text{I wonder whether $\mathcal{B}$ is Abelian. If this is ture (though I can't prove it),}}$ then we know that $\mathcal{B}''$ is Abelian and $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{B}''$ implies that $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{B}''$. Also, if $\mathcal{B}$ is Abelian, then $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{B}'$. But whatever, we cannot conclude that $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{B}'$.

I'm new to this algebraic topic. If this question is too stupid, forgive me. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** According to the comments, I misunderstood the meaning of the book about the definition of *maximal Abelian subalgebra* (fixed now). So now my problem is how to prove the neccessity part.

Comment: Your definition of maximal abelian should include that $\mathcal{B}$ is itself abelian. Otherwise, every algebra $\mathcal{A}$ would be maximal abelian in itself, since there’s no subalgebra properly containing it, much less an abelian subalgebra.

Comment: @AJY That is right! If $\mathcal{A}$ is maximal Abelian, then according to my stated proposition, $\mathcal{A}’=\mathcal{A}$ so $\mathcal{A}$ must be Abelian, which is absurd. Therefore I must misunderstood the meaning of the book. Thanks for your comment ! So, how should I prove the necessity part of the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $B$ is maximal Abelian. Take $x\in B^\prime$. Then $xa=ax$ for all $a\in B$. Thus the algebra $C$ generated by $x$ and $B$ is Abelian. By maximality, $C= B$. As $x\in B^\prime$ was arbitrary, $B^\prime \subseteq B$. The converse inclusion follows from the fact that $B$ is Abelian.